# Is it possible to check whether I have add an observer to NSNotificationCenter before?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

As the title described.

I want to prevent duplicated observer adding so that the selector would not be called twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You can either call `removeObserver` method just before adding observer to make sure you didn't add it twice or subclass `NSNotificationCenter` and register all observers yourself.

P.S. Have you tried adding observer twice? Is your selector also called twice?

Comment: Yes, I added twice and observed two notification calls. However, if I remove a observer that I have not added before, error occurs. Looks like I should add a BOOL variable to achieve such check.

Comment: It might help. But why do you ever need such behaviour? Pattern seems simple - add observer in `viewDidLoad` and remove in `viewDidUnload`.

Comment: Observer may be assign to the view's controller before **OR** after it was loaded, depends on user's need. I would add observer as soon as all conditions are met in both methods. This may cause duplicated adding.

Comment: You could use the `observationInfo` method from NSObject.


`- observationInfo
Returns a pointer that identifies information about all of the observers that are registered with the receiver.`

Comment: Stas, Yes, you might need such behavior.  There are all kinds of other objects besides view controllers that may need to be registered as an observer.